# Using the 'Download ZIP' option on Github Rep with z/OS?

Tags: github, unzip, zos, omvs

Using z/OS 2.5 shell interface using bash:

When using the `Code Download ZIP` option the zip file appears fine but when unzip'd the contents are not tagged as they should be. In my test case the elements (source code) should be tagged as IBM-1047 but after using `unzip` they are ISO-8859.

Any options to resolve this?

Comment: Code Download Zip is from where?   Is the content ISO8859 and you want it converted or its 1047 and its getting autotagged incorrectly?

Comment: example github.com/lbdyck/pdsegen - then click the green Code button and Download ZIP.  The contents are 1047 in my z/OS filesystem from which the git add/commit/push came from. When i do a git clone from the shell on z/OS the files come down correctly

Comment: This is from my `.gitattributes`

`*   git-encoding=utf-8 zos-working-tree-encoding=ibm-1047 linguist-language=REXX`

Comment: And using `less` or `cat` on the `unzip` files that are `ISO-8859` I can read the contents.

Comment: The issue is that using the `zginstall.rex` to create the z/OS datasets from these fails as the z/OS data remains ASCII and is not converted.

Which works just fine for the git clone files.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to update the `zginstall.rex` script to test for ISO-8859 and do an `iconv` to IBM-1047 for those files prior to using the `oget` to copy the file into a z/OS dataset or PDS member.